# Idempotent operators.

Tags: linear-algebra, operator-theory, operator-algebras, idempotents

Apologies first. I am a physicist and my notations and rigour is probably lousy.

If $P$ is an idempotent operator, $P^2 = P$, $P\neq \mathbb1$ and we have $\forall |\psi\rangle$ the relation,

$P.L |\psi\rangle = L|\psi\rangle$, what conclusions can we draw about $L$, which is a linear operator.

1) $L = P$

Are there anything else? If not how does one prove this? Sorry if this is too trivial.

Comment: Is |ψ> allowed to be 0?

Comment: Do we know anything about $|\psi \rangle$ and $L$, or are they completely general?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, all we can really say is that the image of $L$ is not in the kernel of $P.$ Without more information, I'm not sure we can say much more ( and even that assumes that the vector is outside the kernel of $L,$ so is nonzero in particular).

Comment: $|\psi> \neq 0$

Comment: Well,L|ψ> is an eigenvector of P corresponding to the eigenvalue 1, assuming |ψ> is not an element of Ker(L).

Comment: Crossposted to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/122633/2451

Answer (score 2):

If $P^2=P$, then the following are equivalent.

$PLx=Lx$ for every $x$.

The range of $L$ is contained in the range of $P$.

If you were talking about a specific vector $x$, then the following are equivalent:

$PLx=Lx$

$Lx$ is in the range of $P$.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks. What I want to know perhaps a bit naive under what further conditions can we say L = P

Comment: This is never possible. The condition is of course satisfied when $L=P$ but it is always possible that the range of $L$ is a *proper* subset of the range of $P$. It is also possible that the range of $L$ is the same as the range of $P$ but $L$ is not idempotent. For example, if $x$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$ of $P$, $x$ might be an eigenvector with eigenvalue $2$ of $L$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now I understand what you mean... So the conclusion you are drawing, Is that equivalent to this statement